# Como filtrar resultado de um select com base em dado contido em outra tabela?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Boa tarde, Pessoal!

Estou com muita dificuldade para construir um select que seja filtrado com base em um dado contido em outra tabela.

Para contextualizar: Trata-se de um sistema de gerenciamento de armazém (WMS) e preciso trazer como resultado de uma consulta todas as ondas (cargas) que estão em processo de separação, para isso existem 2 tabelas para me auxiliar:

Tabela "saidapornf" possui os campos "idonda" que é o identificador da carga e "psepiniciada" que me retorna de 0 a 100 a porcentagem atual de separação daquela carga.

Através da tabela acima consigo exatamente saber o que preciso, qual carga está em separação, no entanto, preciso fazer um filtro com base no "Armazém" visto que dentro deste sistema temos vários armazéns e quero trazer as cargas em separação apenas de um armazém específico (armazém de id 5).

Para isso, existe a tabela ***"romaneiopai"*** que também contém a coluna **"idonda"** assim como a tabela acima e o campo **"idarmazem"** que traz justamente o armazém qual aquela onda (ou carga) pertence.

Então construi o seguinte select:

```
SELECT v_saidapornf.idonda, v_saidapornf.psepiniciada, romaneiopai.idarmazem 
FROM v_saidapornf, romaneiopai
WHERE  romaneiopai.idarmazem = 5 and v_saidapornf.psepiniciada BETWEEN 1 and 99
```

E o resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que de fato ele me trouxe apenas as ondas de armazém = 5, no entanto, existem ondas nesse resultado que não pertecenem ao armazém 5, ele trouxe apenas porque elas também estão em separação, mas pertencem a outro armazém (como por exemplo a onda 4218 pertence ao armazém 40) e no resultado deste select está populado com o armazém de número 5.

Como eu poderia fazer para que esta consulta me traga realmente apenas as ondas que pertencem ao armazém 5 pessoal?

Muito obrigado a todos!!

Comment: Sem passar os DDL's da tabela fica difícil opinar, mas o que está fazendo é um produto cartesiano. Você deveria passar a condição do JOIN (coluna) no comando `FROM`. Pela descrição do problema o que você precisa é um `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: `FROM v_saidapornf, romaneiopai` aqui tem duas tabelas, para usar mais de uma tabela é preciso fazer o JOIN entre elas, senão o banco não sabe como relacionar e vai fazer um "cartesiado" das tabelas. Como comentou o @Danizavtz, faça o JOIN entre essas duas tabelas

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas pessoal, mas consegui resolver o problema sem fazer o JOIN, a clausula where ficou assim " WHERE v_saidapornf.idonda = romaneiopai.idonda and romaneiopai.idarmazem = 5 and v_saidapornf.psepiniciada BETWEEN 1 and 99" - a diferença ai é que adicionei o  v_saidapornf.idonda = romaneiopai.idonda no inicio da condição e ele me trouxe somente as ondas que realmente pertencem ao armazém 5.

Comment: Você fez justamente o JOIN ...

Comment: @Motta mas sem utilizar o comando de forma explicita? Não sabia que era possível, estou estudnado e tenho um conhecimento ainda raso de SQL. obrigado amigos!